# Docker mounted volume files owned by nobody:nobody (loosing owner)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions, docker-volume, file-ownership

Mounted the .ssh folder into a docker container.

permissions on the host (`ls -laHF`):

```
total 40K
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K Apr  7 21:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 git git 4.0K Apr  7 21:20 ../
-rw------- 1 git git 2.7K Apr  7 21:27 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 git git 2.6K Dec 11 15:34 authorized_keys_1675190689.gitea_bak
-rw------- 1 git git   25 Dec 11 14:02 environment
-rw------- 1 git git  411 Apr  7 21:25 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git   96 Apr  7 21:25 id_ed25519.pub
-rw------- 1 git git 3.4K Dec 11 14:16 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git  740 Dec 11 14:16 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git  222 Dec 11 14:24 known_hosts
```

when i go to the mount in the container and do the same the owner changed:

```
total 40K
drwxr-xr-x    2 nobody   nobody      4.0K Apr  7 21:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x    5 git      git         4.0K Dec 11 14:09 ../
-rw-------    1 nobody   nobody      2.6K Apr  7 21:27 authorized_keys
-rw-------    1 nobody   nobody      2.5K Dec 11 15:34 authorized_keys_1675190689.gitea_bak
-rw-------    1 nobody   nobody        25 Dec 11 14:02 environment
-rw-------    1 nobody   nobody       411 Apr  7 21:25 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody        96 Apr  7 21:25 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-------    1 nobody   nobody      3.3K Dec 11 14:16 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody       740 Dec 11 14:16 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody       222 Dec 11 14:24 known_hosts
```

the volumes are mounted with

```yaml
services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - /home/git/.ssh:/data/git/.ssh
```

Does anyone have any idea how that can be possible?

i have tried mounting the same folder into another container with
`docker run -it -v /home/git/.ssh:/data/git/.ssh ubuntu:latest`
This time all files are owned by `nobody:nogroup` (before it was `nobody:nobody`),
so the problem is not with the service inside the container

Comment: Why are you looking inside the container user and group? is there any specific error or reason that makes you to look there?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Facing the same thing right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my user (in this case `git`) wasn't in the `docker` group.

The group can be added with `sudo usermod -aG docker git`

Answer (score -1):

Every docker image will have a Dockerfile in Github check is that have USER instruction line, which is not exactly the user you have on your host machine. To get the hostmachine UID, GID and then use them to create containers we can [specify the 'user'][1] attribute as :

```yaml
        image: alpine
        user: "${UID}:${GID}"


  [1]: https://blog.giovannidemizio.eu/2021/05/24/how-to-set-user-and-group-in-docker-compose/
```

Comment: This is irrlevant to the question, which is why is the owner of mounted files changed in the container.